# Error using rake for rails 1.2.3 on rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I am trying to install a rails 1.2.3 app on my machine. My machine is currently using rails 3.2.6 , ruby 1.9.3 and windows 7. While trying to use 'RAKE', I am getting the following error

```
  WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  
  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
```

How shall I figure out the problem in order to be able to use my application.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Rakefile` you should change the `require` statements as rake demands it. There might be follow up errors so it would be best to update Rake to match your rails version.